# Remove a vertical whitespace in an itemize list, within a longtblr table

Tags: itemize, longtblr

I have an `itemize` list inside a `longtblr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{enumitem} % <-- for a compact itemize list

\begin{document}


\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  colsep=4pt,
  hline{odd}={solid},
  row{odd}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{even}={abovesep=0pt},
  cell{even}{1} = {c=2}{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j}
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item first item
        \item second item
        \item third item
        \item fourth item
        \item fifth item
        \item sixth item
    \end{itemize} &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]
How can I remove the vertical whitespace between `01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\` and the start/top of the`itemize` list?

This is my desired output:
[image]

Comment: any suggestion? To me, it looks like that ```topsep=0pt``` does not work here.... maybe it is in conflict with the ```\\``` symbol... even though the latter is necessary to go down to the following line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `tabularray`'s documentation section 5.10 Library varwidth

- with `\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}`
- and `measure=vbox,stretch=-1`

**The full code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}%<-- added
\usepackage{enumitem} % <-- for a compact itemize list

\begin{document}


\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[
presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
colspec = {l X},
colsep=4pt,
hline{odd}={solid},
row{odd}={belowsep=0pt},
row{even}={abovesep=0pt},
cell{even}{1} = {c=2}{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j},
measure=vbox,stretch=-1,%<-- added
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nosep]
        \item first item
        \item second item
        \item third item
        \item fourth item
        \item fifth item
        \item sixth item
    \end{itemize} &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! :-)