# Longtblr does not break properly and leaves whitespace

Tags: page-breaking, itemize, white-space, longtblr

How to make `longtblr` break properly and automatically, without leaving whitespace at the bottom of the page?
In other words, I would like that the text arrives to the bottom of the page, and after that continues to the following page.
In my case, `longtblr` does not break the items of an `itemize` list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{enumitem} % <-- for a compact itemize list

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  colsep=4pt,
  hline{odd}={solid},
  row{odd}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{even}={abovesep=0pt},
  cell{even}{1} = {c=2}{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j}
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First
    \item Second
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A
            \item B
            \item C
            \item D
            \item E
        \end{itemize}
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
    \item Fifth
\end{itemize} 
    &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest you add `*` right after `01/01/2018--31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\\`.

Comment: HI! If I add ```*```, and I get this ```01/01/2018--31/12/2019 & \textbf{Second}\\*```, that line (i.e. ```01/01/2018--31/12/2019 & Second```) goes to the following page, and the whitespace is still there... and the items in ```itemize``` are not broken.....

Comment: it looks like that the ```itemize``` environment is uncontrollable once inside the ```logntblr``` environment.... Another issue/example is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713161/remove-a-vertical-whitespace-in-an-itemize-list-within-a-longtblr-table

Comment: Is there anything else that could be done to get items inside the ```longtblr``` environments?

Comment: More generally, it doesn't look like it's useful to employ any kind of table setup here. Please explain what you're trying to achieve by setting up a two-column table for the material at hand.

Comment: Well, I use a table just to have that structure, it is for my clarity and organization of the text....maybe there are other structures which are more friendly with ```itemize```, but I do not know... I like the current organization of the text, and I would like to keep the same or something similar... maybe ```longtable``` has not all these issues with ```itemize```....also most of my texts are organised as bullet points, and therefore I would need ```itemize``` or something similar..

Comment: It's just that the information you've chosen to provide doesn't justify using a table structure.

Comment: ah ok, so, I do not know what else I can use to get the same structure..